# Application Logs - Tracking and Maintenance using MySQL or Text

Tags: php, mysql

We are developing inventory management system and would like to maintain application log, like product added date, added by, modified by ...

These logs need to be maintained for long term usage.

Currently, I am using PHP to write these logs into MySQL database. Now the problem is, Log table in database grow larger than large. Hence I decided to move these logs into text file instead of storing in MySQL.

My Question: If I write the logs in text file, Any Performance issue/Dead log issue arise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There could potentially be issues if you try and write two things to the file at the same time without using an advisory locking system. Have you considered writing the log to MySQL but archiving it to a text file every week? That would keep the database size down and avoid any issues with locking.